# Not getting latest (Major) version SPFile in ItemUpdated

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, event-receivers

I have a Document Library with versioning enabled. After someone has approved a document, the word document gets converted to a pdf with Muhimbi and gets copied to the intranet (other site collection).

In the Item updated method I cannot access the major version (I can for `SPListItem` but not for `SPFile`). The `SPFile.Openbinary()` only gets me the binary of the last/current minor version.

The problem is that we use the version label in our Template (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508229/how-can-i-include-value-of-sharepoints-version-column-in-a-word-document#answer-590444). How do I get the binary data of the Major version in `ItemUpdated`? I need this before converting the document with Muhimbi. Or is the Major Version officially saved after the event receiver is done? Now I seem to convert the minor version to pdf which shows in the version label.

I am using SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that `ItemUpdated` event is fired several times during approval.

Is yes, you can check the Level property of `SPListItem` or `SPFile` and do your code when major version is published.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it solved. I did a SystemUpdate at the beginning of the Event Receover and then reloaded my SPListItem.